# How to filter objects from template?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I have 2 models `Category` and `Spending` where `Category` is one of the `Spending` fields.

User can create custom categories and add spending on the webpage.

The question is, how to filter spendings by categories in Template?

I have:

```
{% for category in categories %}
    {% for spending in spendings %} 'I want this FOR have only spendings from this category.'
```

I know how to filter objects with Object.objects.filter() but I am not sure it applies here, because categories are dynamic here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the reverse relation. You haven't shown your models, but presumably there is a foreign key from Spending to Category. If so:

```
{% for spending in category.spending_set.all %}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for a quick response. Indeed, forgot about them, here they are https://gist.github.com/Jbwzx/9b6548ab30e27173502cfc80ab6348a6 Do reverse relation still applies

Comment: Yes, why wouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks a lot mate. Solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way.

```
{% for category in categories %}
     {% for spending in category.spending_set.all %}
         {{spending}}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```